# How to access Azure SQL database from AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc, aws-glue

I have SQL database in Azure and trying to access from AWS using the AWS Glue Service. i am not able to connect . Looks like I have to do  some settings in VPC inbound/outbound and , So that it can able to access the database outside of the VPC. Any suggestions or direction pls ?